# Android BLE not able to enable BLE Notify

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, iot

**Working :- We are able**

1. To discover BLE devices from our mobile application.
2. To connect from one of available listed device nearby.
3. To write a character from application on ble device ( device is able to receive we already checked).

**Not Working:-  We are not able**

To read the message sent by the BLE device from our application
Problem Statement:- To receive the data from the BLE we need to enable the notifier service first before sending commands.

We are using custom service with UUID (d973f2e0-b19e-11e2-9e96-0800200c9a66) to perform read and write operations

We are able to write characters(N or F) with this Characteristic UUID (d973f2e0-b19e-11e2-9e96-0800200c9a66) from above service

For read operation or getting response of write operation we have to enable Notifier from this UUID(d973f2e0-b19e-11e2-9e96-0800200c9a66 ) and once its enable we can get response from BLE device to phone.

But we are not able to enable that notifier mentioned above mentioned.

Comment: Why are you not able to?

Comment: What happens then?

Comment: thanks for response resolved this issue.

Comment: https://androidpedia.net/en/tutorial/10020/bluetooth-low-energy

Comment: i was not able to enable notification and i forgot to enable descriptor, so i did the same and got response.